# IDA disassembler view of loaded DLL in process address space

Tags: dll, x86-64, disassembly, ida, wow64

I'm using [IDA](https://hex-rays.com/ida-free/) to understand the Wow64 subsystem on Windows 64. I loaded a 32 bit PE executable into IDA.

I'd like to view all the DLL loaded in the process's address space (there should be actually two ntdll versions, namely the 32 bit version and the 64 bit one).

Can you help me ? Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think both the 64-bit and 32-bit versions of `ntdll` get loaded into a process' address space?

Comment: @Dai See here [Wow64](https://www.mandiant.com/resources/blog/wow64-subsystem-internals-and-hooking-techniques) and [here](https://medium.com/@fsx30/hooking-heavens-gate-a-wow64-hooking-technique-5235e1aeed73).  The `ntdll` 64 bit version is loaded in process's address space since it actually performs the syscall when the processor is switched in 64 bit mode from compatibility mode.